# Continue Ubuntu 14.04 LTS upgrade after stalled midway

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I was tryin to upgrade my Saucy Salamander to Trusty Tahr today morning, but due to intermittent connection breaks on my network, the process failed. It was downloading the packages (about 1500 completed from about 1875 packages).

I restarted the update twice and both times the update process was stalled, which resulted in an error that it could not download the packages and the system would be restored to the original version.

Is there any way to continue the update process from where it left (ie, 1500 out of 1875 packages) and go on with the update...?

I have restarted the update way too many times and the it would get stalled by the same network error, and i have lost my patience.

I am only asking this because i have also updated windows 8 to 8.1 and no matter what sort of network break occurs, it would start from where it left (ie, the amount of update files downloaded).

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The upgrade manager will not download a package twice unless you have issued an `apt-get clean` first. So yes, restarting the upgrade manager will pick up where it left off

Comment: Now, when i try to update using the Software Updater, it says that only a partial update can be done due a update that went haywire the previous time i tried. Should i go ahead with the partial upgrade or is there something else i should do ?

Comment: Enter the command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`; this will tell you what exactly has gone wrong, and what you should do now. If in doubt, post the output here and we'll take a look.